# Keep only matched words in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I want to keep only those words which are present in my list. All other words should get deleted.(pandas dataframe)

```
cuisine_list = ['breakfast', 'american', 'tea', 'chicken']
```

| name | cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| dominos pizza | breakfast american tea dine in |
| kfc | american chicken play area |

The result should look like this-

| name | cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| dominos pizza | breakfast american tea |
| kfc | american chicken |

I am using following code but its taking lot of time.

```
 file1_cuisine = file1[["Cuisine"]]

for index, row in file1_cuisine.iterrows():
    words_to_keep = []
    for word in row[0].split(' '):
        if word in words_to_match :
            words_to_keep.append(word + ' ')
    file1_cuisine.loc[index, 'final_input_text']= ''.join(words_to_keep)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function with `split` and set intersection, last join values by `,`:

```
cuisine_list = ['breakfast', 'american', 'tea', 'chicken']
df['cuisine'] = df['cuisine'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.split()).intersection(cuisine_list)))

print (df)
            name                 cuisine
0  dominos pizza  tea,breakfast,american
1            kfc        chicken,american
```

Or use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
cuisine_list = ['breakfast', 'american', 'tea', 'chicken']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in cuisine_list)
df['cuisine'] = df['cuisine'].str.findall(rf'{pat}').str.join(',')

print (df)
            name                 cuisine
0  dominos pizza  breakfast,american,tea
1            kfc        american,chicken
```

Comment: Than you for the answer @jezrael

Comment: @RajeshMORE - working well? Values in list has only one word?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`set intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) using `&` with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [760]: y = set(cuisine_list)
In [766]: df['cuisine'] = df['cuisine'].str.split().apply(lambda x: list(set(x) & y)).str.join(',')
    
In [767]: df
Out[767]: 
            name                 cuisine
0  dominos pizza  tea,american,breakfast
1            kfc        chicken,american
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can we remove brackets and keep only commas

Comment: @Mayank better move `set(cuisine_list)` out of `apply` (use a variable), this avoids defining it at each loop. Also, aggregate directly in the first apply (no need to loop twice)

Comment: @Rajesh use `','.join` in place of `list` as "aggregation" function

Comment: @RajeshMORE I've updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: @mozway Thanks. I've incorporated your suggestions in my answer.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I meant to do all in `apply` (every time you're calling `str` or `apply` you perform a new loop). But this is now what jezrael's answer is doing ;)